# WCF Named Pipe Server Fails With AddressAccessDeniedException

Tags: c#, wcf, named-pipes

I have a process which is hosting a WCF Named Pipe server.

The process runs under a user account with no admin privileges.
When a client tries to connect to the pipe it receives a timeout exception and the server fails with the following exception:

> Throwing an exception. Source: System.ServiceModel 4.0.0.0. Exception details: System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException: Cannot listen on pipe 'net.pipe://localhost/path/to/endpoint': Access is denied. (5, 0x5) ---> System.IO.PipeException: Cannot listen on pipe 'net.pipe://localhost/path/to/endpoint': Access is denied. (5, 0x5)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnectionListener.CreatePipe()
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnectionListener.BeginAccept(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionAcceptor.AcceptIfNecessary(Boolean startAccepting)

After reading [Chris Dickson's blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20110825060451/http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/chrisdi/archive/2008/06/23/exploring-the-wcf-named-pipe-binding-part-3.aspx), I can think of three possible things that cause this:

1. Somehow, the user in not being added to the ACL
2. The user is not given the FILE_CREATE_PIPE_INSTANCE permission
3. The deny ACE for the Network Users group is denying permission

Notes:

- Using a non-WCF named pipe, adding current user and the built-in administrator to the ACL works just fine.
- A similar endpoint in a process running under a SYSTEM account works just fine.
- When testing the code under my own user account everything works fine.
- The host must remain a process and must have non-admin privileges.
- I tried adding the current user and the built-in administrator to the ACL as suggested in [Chris Dickson's blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20110825060451/http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/chrisdi/archive/2008/06/23/exploring-the-wcf-named-pipe-binding-part-3.aspx) but it did not help.
- I tried setting NetNamedPipeSecurityMode to None but that didn't help either.